# « Le Loyre » de Joachim du Bellay

Tags: genre, noms-propres, poésie, géographie

Dans *[Les Regrets](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Regrets_%28du_Bellay%29)* de Joachim du Bellay (le fameux “Heureux qui, comme Ulysse, a fait un beau voyage”), on lit [au sonnet XXXI](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Regrets_%28du_Bellay%29#XXXI):

> Plus me plaist le séjour qu’ont basty mes ayeux,
>   Que des palais Romains le front audacieux,
>   Plus que le marbre dur me plaist l’ardoise fine,
>
> **Plus mon Loyre Gaulois**, que le Tybre Latin,
>   Plus mon petit Lyré, que le mont Palatin,
>   Et plus que l’air marin la doulceur Angevine.

Ce “Loyre” me tracasse. Pour que l'alexandrin soit de la bonne longueur, il lui faut 2 syllabes.  Je n'ai pas d'édition de référence, mais on trouve selon les sources sur Internet plusieurs écritures “modernisées” :

- “mon Loir”, qui ne fait pour sûr qu'une syllabe ;
- “mon Loire”, probablement une modernisation partielle de l'orthographe, mais il n'est pas de rivière appelée “le Loire” ;
- “ma Loire”, qui fait la bonne longueur

Parmi les explications possibles, j'ai lu :

- il s'agit de la Loire, mais le masculin est utilisé [parce que c'est le cas en latin](http://lechatsurmonepaule.over-blog.fr/article-joachim-du-bellay-heureux-qui-comme-ulysse-50059437.html) (argument qui me semble peu convaincant)
- il s'agit du Loir, mais la prononciation a évolué (j'en doute : Loire et Loir auraient alors été homophones, ce qui me semble peu probable)

Alors, avez-vous accès à une explication “de référence” ? Est-ce la Loire, ou le Loir, et sait-on pour quelle raison du Bellay l'écrit ainsi ?

Comment: +1 parce que ça m'a fait plonger dans les vieilles cartes et que j'aime les cartes !

Comment: Je ne comprends pas le problème avec les syllabes. La façon de le lire change-t-elle selon qu'il s'agit de l'une ou l'autre des propositions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vu la comparaison avec Le Tybre, je pense qu'on peut raisonnablement estimer qu'il parle de la rivière (curieusement, en plus de la Loire, il existe une *Loyre* en Corrèze mais j'imagine qu'il ne parlait pas de celle-là). Quant à l'utilisation du masculin... peut-être que le genre du nom n'était pas encore bien fixé à l'époque? Ou qu'il considérait que tous les fleuves devaient être masculins?

Mais plutôt que d'essayer de deviner, je pense que le plus simple est de chercher [d'autres utilisations de *Loyre*](http://www.google.com/search?hl=fr&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22#sclient=psy&hl=fr&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22%20loyre&pbx=1&oq=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22%20loyre&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=10265l11825l0l11981l6l5l0l0l0l0l202l499l0.2.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8b2e48661c7dbf37&biw=1680&bih=910) dans ses textes.

On trouve [par exemple](http://books.google.com/books?id=EQ8zCZmNXq8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22%20loyre&hl=fr&ei=OLFUTvmWBYOVswav_7njDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=loyre&f=false):

> Loyre fameux, qui ta petite source
>   Enfles de maintz gros fleuves et ruysseaux,
>   Et qui de loing coules tes cleres eaux
>   En l'Ocean d'une assez vive course:
>
> Ton chef royal hardiment bien hault pousse
>   Et apparoy entre tous les plus beaux,
>   Comme un Thaureau sur les menuz troupeaux,
>   Quoy que le Pau envieux s'en courrousse.
>
> Commande doncq' aux gentiles Naïades
>   Sortir dehors leurs plbeaux palais humides
>   Avecques toy, leur fleuve paternel,
>
> Pour saluer de joyeuses aubades
>   Celle qui t'a, et tes filles liquides,
>   Deifié de ce bruyt eternel.

Où on voit clairement que notre bonhomme considère <strike>la Loire</strike> le Loyre comme masculin, et paternel de surcroit.

[Un autre livre semble aborder le sujet directement](http://books.google.com/books?id=iKNcAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22%20loyre&dq=inauthor%3a%22Joachim%20Du%20Bellay%22%20loyre&hl=fr&ei=irNUTs-RMc3tsgbEh5gV&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ).

Answer (score 10):

S'agissant d'un des plus célèbres poètes du bord de la Loire, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait le moindre doute sur le fleuve dont il s'agit (et le parallèle avec le Tibre garantit plus ou moins qu'il s'agit d'un fleuve). À noter que [dans un autre poème](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/joachim_du_bellay/au_fleuve_de_loire.html) (portant clairement sur le fleuve en question), Bellay donne aussi du masculin:

> **Au fleuve de Loire**
>
> Ô de qui la vive course
>
> Prend sa bienheureuse source,
>
> D'une argentine fontaine,
>
> Qui d'une fuite lointaine,
>
> *etc*

À vrai dire, il n'est pas particulièrement clair que la Loire devrait être féminin. En général, le genre des toponymes est hérité du mot qu'ils représentent (ex: "la ville de Paris" => "Paris meurtrie" etc.). Puisqu'il s'agit d'un fleuve, le masculin serait logique (comme pour **le** Rhône ou **le** Rhin). Le féminin évoquant plutôt une rivière (cela dit: nombre d'autres "fleuves" sont au féminin, je sais)...

J'imagine que pour une raison ou une autre, ce masculin est devenu féminin après la Renaissance.

Comment: On a oublié le ngram obligatoire: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=le+Loire%2Cla+Loire&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3

Comment: @Joubarc: sauf quand l'occurrence, le ngramme ne dit pas grand chose, à part que les livres étaient beaucoup moins courant (et moins numérisés) au XVIè siècle que maintenant :-)

Comment: Ca doit être pour ça qu'on l'a oublié :-)

Answer (score 7):

A la double combinatoire Loire/Tibre et Lyré/Palatin du Bellay superpose une double comparaison fleuve/ville Rome/Gaule (puisque Lyré est son village natal et que "les regrets" ont été composés à Rome).

Cette double symétrie est rompue si on n'interprète pas Loyre comme le fleuve.  Il y a bien un autre cours d'eau nommé [Loyre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyre) aujourd'hui, mais *la Loire* est beaucoup plus proche de Liré que *la Loyre*.

Answer (score 5):

[Du Bellay n'est pas lui-même cohérent sur le genre du nom du fleuve](http://books.google.com/books?id=LAFAAAAAYAAJ&&q=Loyre#v=snippet&q=Loyre&f=false) (la [concordance](http://books.google.com/books?id=zndMHZPMCsUC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=%22le+loyre%22&source=bl&ots=P1lRPleReo&sig=LUsAXu1y6jkOUKDhOsql2lldOBI&hl=en&ei=bndVTsWnO_T34QT1sO2HBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22le%20loyre%22&f=false) trouve plus d'occurrences), puisqu'il écrit aussi :

> Tout au plus pres, où Loyre plus profonde [*Chant Triomphal*, 171]

Et ce n'est pas qu'il confond avec le Loir :

> Du Lot, du Loyr, de la Touvre, et de Loyre [*Vers Lyriques*, “La Louange du feu Roy François et du Treschrestien Roy Henry”, 12]

Je n'ai pas de référence là-dessus, mais je soupçonne que le genre était fluctuant à l'époque, en train de couler du masculin hérité du latin vers un féminin peut-être influencé par la finale `-e` ou par le risque de confusion avec le Loyre et le Loir.

Answer (score 3):

Pour ce qui est de l'orthographe, les [cartes de Cassini](http://jzani.free.fr/cassini/maps/98.jpg) (1750-1790), utilisent déjà Loire. Il en est de même avec une [carte](http://www.henri-iv.culture.fr/medias/communs/images/grand_format/0/8_4.jpg) fin XVIème (il faut sortir la loupe).

Cependant, j'ai trouvé dans un [livre de 1580](http://books.google.com/books?id=oKMv6cuzX9UC&pg=PA340&lpg=PA340&dq=angevin%20loyre&source=bl&ots=ewJFq7yLtB&sig=3wpkJ1YHlUbb6wTysEm_545xpkI&hl=en&ei=-rlUTs3sJMjk4QT6z8WpBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), le *De la demonomanie des sorciers* par *J. Bodin Angevin*, une référence à Fleury sur Loire, qui est en bord de fleuve, en tant que Fleury-sur-Loyre.

[image]

> [...]s'appelait Gilbert, c'était un moine de ***Fleury sur Loyre***, qui avait bien étudié en sa jeunesse, qui fut pédagogue de Robert [...]

Possible que l'ancien français en Loyre soit resté dans le patois angevin qui devait être répandu alors.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai toujours entendu expliquer, soit au lycée soit en fac, que Du Bellay désignait "LE Loir".

L'argument qui me paraît le plus convaincant, c'est que si on y voit la Loire, les comparatifs des deux derniers tercets perdent toute leur cohérence. En effet, à chaque fois, Du Bellay compare un emblème glorieux & imposant de Rome avec des petites choses de son Anjou natal.

Il n'y aurait aucun sens, dans ces conditions, à mentionner la Loire, fleuve nettement plus impressionnant que le Tibre, ayant à la fois une longueur et un débit bien supérieurs.

Answer (score 0):

Moi je dirais qu'il s'agit du Loir, la famille du Bellay possédait un château du coté de Lavenay, sur les bords du Loir et du Tusson, où il aimait  à rencontrer Ronsard dont la maison natale de Couture sur le Loir est toute proche…

Comment: Et je compte les pieds, et je tombe par terre. (« Pour que l'alexandrin soit de la bonne longueur, il lui faut 2 syllabes. »)

Answer (score -1):

bah *Liger* est le mot latin **masculin** qui est l'origine du mot Loire, et Du Bellay ne l'ignore pas ;-)

Comment: F'x ne l'ignore pas, mais trouve l'argument « peu convaincant ».

Comment: @Gilles bien d'accord. Je pencherais plutôt pour le fait que les fleuve et rivières personnifiés de la mythologie classiques (*potamoi*) sont masculins.